# Finding an ellipse tangent to a circle when its center and semi-minor axis are given

Tags: graphics, geometry

I'm doing a geometry study between a circle and an ellipse.

After several attempts with Mathematica I had no choice but to use other software to obtain the values of the **$r_x$**, **$\theta _1$** and **$\theta _2$**.

[image]

The results obtained by the other software were:

[image]

According to the documentation I need these parameters to get an ellipse:

$\text{Circle}\left[\{x,y\},\left\{r_x,r_y\right\},\left\{\theta _1,\theta _2\right\}\right]$

$r_x=11.4935$

$\theta _1=2 \pi +0.023$

$\theta _2=\pi -0.023$

With these values I was able to create what I wanted:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
g1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.006], Circle[{0, 0}, 19]}];
g2 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], Circle[{0, 15}, {11.4935, 1.5}, {2 Pi + 0.023, Pi - 0.023}]}];
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]

I did an analysis to get the points where there is the tangency of the geometries using the equation of the circle and the equation of the ellipse:

$ \left(x-x_0\right){}^2+\left(y-y_0\right){}^2=r^2$

[image]

$ \frac{\left(x-x_0\right){}^2}{a^2}+\frac{\left(y-y_0\right){}^2}{b^2}=1$

[image]

I noticed that the results were right

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 11.4935;
Solve[((x - 0)^2 + (y - 0)^2 == 19^2) && ((x - 0)^2/a^2 + (y - 15)^2/1.5^2 == 1), {x, y}] // N
```

> ${{x -> -11.3197 - 0.0000200237 I,
> y -> 15.2599 - 0.0000148534 I}, {x -> 11.3197 + 0.0000200237 I,
> y -> 15.2599 - 0.0000148534 I}, {x -> -11.3197 + 0.0000200237 I,
> y -> 15.2599 + 0.0000148534 I}, {x -> 11.3197 - 0.0000200237 I,
> y -> 15.2599 + 0.0000148534 I}}$

[image]

The question is as follows:

What should I do to get the values of the **$r_x$**, **$\theta _1$** and **$\theta _2$**?

The geometries must be tangent, but I do not know how to do it ...

Comment: Can you explain what "largest radius of the ellipse" and "angles of the ellipse" mean? I see no actual ellipse in any of your images. What ellipse are you looking at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The circle.

```
Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 19^2, y]
```

> `{{y -> -Sqrt[361 - x^2]}, {y -> Sqrt[361 - x^2]}}`

```
D[Sqrt[361 - x^2], x]
```

> `-(x/Sqrt[361 - x^2])`

The ellipse.

```
With[{b = 3/2}, 
  Simplify[Solve[x^2/a^2 + (y - 15)^2/b^2 == 1, y], a > 0]]
```

> `{{y -> 15 - (3 Sqrt[a^2 - x^2])/(2*a)}, {y -> 15 + (3 Sqrt[a^2 - x^2])/(2*a)}}`

```
D[15 + (3 Sqrt[a^2 - x^2])/(2 a), x]
```

> `-((3 x)/(2 a Sqrt[a^2 - x^2]))`

The points of tangency are the points where the two curves intersect and have the same derivatives. We make use of this to find `a`.

```
Solve[
  {Sqrt[361 - x^2] == 15 + (3 Sqrt[a^2 - x^2])/(2 a), 
   x/Sqrt[361 - x^2] == (3 x)/(2 a Sqrt[a^2 - x^2])}, 
  {a, x}]
```

[image: solutions]

Now we can draw the figure.

```
With[{a = 1/2 Sqrt[1/2 (553 + 5 Sqrt[10153])], b = 3/2}, 
  Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 19], Circle[{0, 15}, {a, b}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {12 {-1, 1}, {13, 19.2}}]]
```

[image: figure]

#### Update

For the record, here is the computation of the two angles `θ1` and `θ2` that allow the section of the ellipse lying above the two tangents points to be clipped out of the figure.

```
a1 = N[(1/2) Sqrt[(1/2) (553 + 5 Sqrt[10153])]];
b1 = 1.5;
```

x-coordinates of the points of tangency.

```
x1 = -N[Sqrt[-(10153/288) + (467 Sqrt[10153])/288]]; (* left *)
x2 = -x1; (* right *)
```

Translating the ellipse to the origin to get `y1`.

```
y1 = N[Sqrt[361 - x2^2] - 15];
```

This next calculation is a little tricky. Because of the way Mathematica draws ellipses by stretching circles, it is necessary to reverse the stretch of the y-commponent when computing the angles.

```
θ = ArcTan[x2, y1 a1/b1]];
θ1 = π - θ;
θ2 = θ + 2 π;

Graphics[
  {Circle[{0, 0}, 19], 
   Circle[{0, 15}, {a1, b1}, {θ1, θ2}],
   Red, Point[{{x1, 15 + y1}, {x2, 15 + y2}}]},
  PlotRange -> {12 {-1, 1}, {12.9, 19.2}}]
```

[image: figure]

Comment: Now I just need to find $\theta_ 1$ and $\theta_ 2$

Comment: @LCarvalho. Since you know the ellipse center `{0, 15}` and my answer gives the `x` values of the tangents, you can solve for the `y` values from the equation of the circle. With those three points, finding the angles is not hard.

Comment: That's exactly what I'll do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is totally with reference to the [m_goldberg answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147245/finding-an-ellipse-tangent-to-a-circle-when-its-center-and-semi-minor-axis-are-g/147255#147255), but with some changes because some steps were manually entered and I want to make everything automatic.

Some unwanted messages will appear, so I'll leave clean outputs

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Off[Solve::ratnz]
Off[General::ivar]
```

A general function for the circle equation was created. The [`Circle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html) function already exists, but the output of this function will give me the equation as a function of `x`.

```
eqCircle[x0_, y0_, r_] := 
 Solve[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 == r^2, y] /. Rule -> Set // Last
```

I will highlight the variable `r` because it will be used in function as in graphics.

```
r = 19;
eqCircle[0, 0, r]
```

> $\left\{\sqrt{361-x^2}\right\}$

```
g1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.006], Circle[{0, 0}, r]}]
```

[image]

As the variable `y` received a value through `eqCircle` function I will save its value in another variable and clear the memory so that the variable `y` receives another value when passing through `eqEllipse` function.

```
eqC = y
Clear[y];
```

> $\left\{\sqrt{361-x^2}\right\}$

The points of tangency are the points where the two curves intersect and have the same derivatives. Below is the derivative of the `circle` equation.

```
dy1 = D[eqC, x]
```

> $-\frac{x}{\sqrt{361-x^2}}$

I will highlight the variable `b` because it will be used in the function as in graphics.
I will highlight the variable `y0Ellipse` because it will be used to get the variable $\theta$

```
b = 1.5;
x0Ellipse = 0;
y0Ellipse = 15;
eqEllipse[x0_, y0_, a_, b_] := 
 Solve[(x - x0)^2/a^2 + (y - y0)^2/b^2 == 1, y] /. Rule -> Set // Last
eqEllipse[x0Ellipse, y0Ellipse, a, b]
```

> $\left\{1.5 \left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1. x^2}}{a}+10.\right)\right\}$

As the variable `y` has received a value through `eqEllipse` function I will save its value in another variable and clear the memory.

```
eqE = y
Clear[y];
```

> $1.5 \left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1. x^2}}{a}+10.\right)$

The points of tangency are the points where the two curves intersect and have the same derivatives. Below is the derivative of the `ellipse` equation.

```
dy2 = D[eqE, x]
```

> $-\frac{1.5 x}{a \sqrt{a^2-1. x^2}}$

**The solution to the question is here**

Using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) by matching the two specific functions and their derivatives to this scenario I have created the values of the variables `a` and `x`.

Just a remark: At this point only I improved what `m_goldberg` answered by adding the expressions `&& a > 0 && x > 0` to filter the expected results.

```
Solve[{eqC == eqE, dy1 == dy2 && a > 0 && x > 0}, {a, x}] /. 
 Rule -> Set
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  11.4935 & 11.3197 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

To obtain the `angles` that create the section of the ellipse, simply find the angle formed between `eqE-y0Ellipse` and `x`. The variable `x` was obtained by the above resolved.

```
eqE
y0Ellipse
x
θ = ArcTan[x, eqE - y0Ellipse]
```

> $15.2599$
>
> $15$
>
> $11.3197$
>
> $0.0229571$

Here is a chart to make it easier to understand

[image]

Enlarging the image above

[image]

```
g2 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], 
   Circle[{0, 15}, {a, b}, {2 Pi + θ, Pi - θ}]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]